# Styles that are not found in Flex documentation

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

today I wanted to change the border color of TextInput when user has a focus on it. I could not find any style that would allow me to change that. A little bit of Google searching and I found answer to be **themeColor**.

Why is it that there are some styles that work and which are not even mentioned in the Flex documentation? (and how can one find out about em, except doing some web searching?)

Thanx
Ladislav

Comment: I think the themeColor is mentioned in the documentation! http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/TextInput.html#styleSummary ... click on "inherited styles" to see the complete list..

Comment: You are correct, I didn't see that one...well that is nice, it seemed wired to me that Adobe would not say anything about this style inside its documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comment above Srirangan answered the question correctly, but I am not able to accept his comment as answer to my question...so I will just accept this one :)

Answer (score 0):

As always I suggest while managing in color and properties use [Flex Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html) create  a stylesheet.css, put it into src folder and then call it by the following statement:

```
<mx:Style source="yourstylesheet.css" />
```